# BI vs Data Science. Looking for a difference in definitions

Tags: regression

can someone please tell me the difference between a BI trendline, and a linear/exponential regression?

When explaining this to a hardcore BI person, what can be used to mark the difference?   Thanks.

Comment: How is your trend line calculated, if not by linear regression; GLM? When I hear "line" I inevitably think of linear regression.

Comment: ok. rephrase,  what does a linear/exponential regression answer that a BI trendline does not?  thanks.

Comment: And I'm asking you to define how your "BI trendline" is determined.

Comment: In normal circumstances, we use trendlines to show increases and decreases in movement.  a flat line means status quo.

Comment: I understand the purpose, I meant the mathematical definition. Does it differ from linear regression? Not to me. If it does to you, I'm asking you to explain how.

Comment: that's what I'm asking.  I apologize for being difficult.  In most tools, the word "show trendline" does not indicate mathematical definition.  but it appears as it's defined, whether the trend is increasing or decreasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any difference in regression models can be reduced to differences in the latent model (e.g., linear vs. exponential), regularizer (e.g., $L^p$ norm), and loss function. So you can have subtle differences by keeping some of these three parameters fixed while modifying the rest.

My understanding of a BI trend line is that it assumes an affine latent model without saying anything about the regularizer or loss function (though I'd assume it's the MSE unless stated otherwise). In the data science world, you should also state what loss function and regularizer you used if you want to be clear.

Comment: ok.  I didn't know about the use of regularizers as per regression models, as well as loss functions.  This helps me understand more clearly how to define the environment to know whether or not a line is moving in teh wrong direction, even for the right reason.